# How to fill in date in SQL Server 2008 R2 using powershell 3.0?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, powershell, sql-server-2008-r2

I know there are some possibilites to enter data in a table of SQL Server with powershell.
Is there a good guide for that ? I am using Windows authentication to connect to SQL server.

What I need is to add a new to to an existing table and put in 5 values for 5 different columns.

So Can someone give me a guide, how to access SQL through powershell ? using windows authentication. Thanks

Comment: It's a good way like the rest solutions, please clarify your question

Comment: First I need to know how to connect to SQL with windows authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Ado.Net classes. An [example](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh289310.aspx) from Technet. The steps are quite simple: Create a conection and SqlCommand, then execute the command. Like so,

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
$conn.open()
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$cmd.connection = $conn
$cmd.commandtext = "INSERT INTO MyTable (MyColumn) VALUES('{0}')" -f $myVariable
$cmd.executenonquery()
$conn.close()
```

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatement` instead of string building for the query. It's better for performance and more secure.

Answer (score 3):

Use invoke-sqlcmd, it makes life a lot easier and it supports windows authentication and sql server authentication

**If you are using SSMS 2008 you will need to install module SQLPS - it is available here:** https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=ea42395138308430&id=EA42395138308430%21986

If you are using SSMS 2012 it is already available.

**Here is a good general article on setting up your environment:**

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/practical-powershell-for-sql-server-developers-and-dbas-%E2%80%93-part-1/

Comment: I like the idea of `invoke-sqlcmd` but I'm moving away from it personally, for a couple reasons. #1, it introduces an additional dependency for scripts. #2, if you're dealing with arbitrary data, it's far more difficult to protect against SQL injection and other formatting-related issues. #3, it doesn't enforce type checking as early as you would see when using `PreparedStatement`s. For a quick one-off on the command line, I still go to `invoke-sqlcmd` but for production script, I use ADO.NET. And contrary to what your answer implies, ADO.NET objects **do** support both authentication types.

Comment: @alroc - I will note your experience with invoke-sqlcmd - it might come in useful for me in the future...